# Hide or Mask environment variable in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible with any configuration or a script?

[image]

**EDIT**: I just want to hide/mask it when I'm sharing the screen. So when I open the `Environment Variables` window, it's secret value should be hidden.
For example, the way GitLab provides to hide env variables
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235918/is-storing-a-password-in-a-windows-user-environment-variable-bad-practice

Comment: You can encrypt the password, but then you must decrypt it in your script first. In any case, this only protects against novice users, not against an ICT hobbyist or more skilled.

Comment: Environment variables are not a place you should be storing passwords at all. Every program in the system has access to them. If you need that kind of thing then the *slightly* better place would be to set up a script for whatever program it is that sets the environment specifically for that program prior to running it. It's no better security wise than a system-wide environment variable but at least you're not advertising it to anyone who can run `set`.

Comment: Hide or mask from what? If it must not be accessible, why is it there in the first place? This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029): you have a problem which you haven't disclosed (X) and you came up with a misguided solution (Y) which you don't know how to implement. You should ask "how to X" rather than "how to Y".

Comment: @gronostaj, I've edited the question with the problem.

Comment: You appear to have misconceptions about what GitLab does. “Protected” means the variables are simply not set when the CI build is not for a protected branch or tag. “Masked” means the values are removed from logs when they appear. Both of these you cannot have in general, only with CI pipelines. In either case, the values are still visible to all processes in the pipeline.

Comment: Windows does not support what you want.

Comment: @DanielB, I was not referring to the Term "Masked" of GitLab, I just want to show an example of the picture I've attached, whose values are hidden behind "************". I think I got my answer, it's not possible. Anyway, I was already using the `.properties` file to store the secrets. Thank you all!